# Determining the value of constant for joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I would like to know how you would set up your double integral if they give you $x^2$ as in the following example:
$$
(,)= 
\begin{cases}
cx^2y  & \mbox{ for } x^2 ≤ y ≤ 1 \\
0 & \mbox{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Please write out the equation, don’t just link to it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You construct the relevant area as follows:

- Starting from $x^2\leq y \leq 1 \Rightarrow x^2 \leq 1 \Rightarrow |x| \leq 1 \Rightarrow \boxed{-1\leq x \leq 1}$
- The values for $y$ you read directly from the inequality: $x^2 \leq y \leq 1$.

So, the integral is (as shown already in Kavi's solution):
$$\int_{x=-1}^1\int_{y=x^2}^1cx^2y\;dy\; dx$$

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

$c\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{x^{2}}^{1} x^{2} y dydx=1$. This gives $c\int_{-1}^{1} \frac {1-x^{4}} 2 x^{2} dx=1$. I will let you complete it now.

Comment: thank you so much!